# AngularJS: I clearly do not understand the use of ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an extremely hierarchical JSON structure as a scope variable in my AngularJS controller.  I want to loop around different sections of that variable.  I thought about using `ng-init` to specify where in the structure I am.  Here is some code:

**my_app.js:**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("my_app");
  app.controller("MyController", [ "$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.things = {
      name: "a",
      children: [
        { 
          name: "a.a",
          children: [
            { name: "a.a.a" },
            { name: "a.a.b" }
          ]
         },
        { 
          name: "a.b",
          children: [
            { name: "a.b.a" },
            { name: "a.b.b" }
          ]
         }
       ]
    }
  }]);
});
```

**my_template.html:**

```
<div ng-app="my_app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-init="current_thing=things.children[0]" ng-repeat="thing in current_thing.children>
      {{ thing.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would expect this to display a list:

> - a.a.a
> - a.a.b

But it displays nothing.

Of course, if I specify the loop explicitly (`ng-repeat="thing in things.children[0].children"`) it works just fine.  But that little snippet of template code will have to be run at various points in my application at various levels of "things."

*(Just to make life complicated, I can get the current thing level using standard JavaScript or else via Django cleverness.)*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-init` runs at a lower priority (450) than `ng-repeat` (1000).  As a result, when placed on the same element, `ng-repeat` is compiled first meaning that the scope property created by `ng-init` won't be defined until after `ng-repeat` is executed.

As a result, if you want to use it in this manner, you'd need to place it on the parent element instead.

```
<div ng-app="my_app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <ul ng-init="current_thing=things.children[0]">
    <li ng-repeat="thing in current_thing.children>
      {{ thing.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That has fixed this toy example.  It is still not working in the real code, though.  I need to do some more thinking and maybe get back to you.

Comment: My pleasure.  The principles should be the same.  Keep in mind however, that ng-init comes at a cost and that is largely debugging.  It is much harder to debug ng-init over proper data structures in a backing controller.